# PHP variables in javascript issue

Tags: php

I created JavaScript validation into which PHP variables are passed.

```
onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, {$validate['txtUlica']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtUlica']}', '{$def['txtUlica']}')"; ?>"
```

But when trying to verify the PHP variables are set before passing them to the JavaScript with this:

```
  onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, isset({$validate['txtUlica']['options']['regexp']}, '{$greske['txtUlica']})', 'isset({$def['txtUlica']}'))"; ?>"
```

The `isset()` function is parsed as string, could someone help me with this complex situation?

Comment: isset return true/false, so it's used for if normally, what you want to do?

Comment: AIUI you're trying to ensure that the PHP vars are set before passing them to JS?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it as a raw PHP string your problem is here:

"proveriPolje(this, **isset({$validate**['txtUlica']['options']['regexp']},

Using { to break out of the string is in the wrong place and it won't work for functions anyway essentially you're just writing "isset" as part of the output string - try something like this (which should pass an empty string to the JS if the PHP isn't set):

```
onblur="<?= "proveriPolje(this, " 
    . "'" . ( isset($validate['txtUlica']['options']['regexp']) ? $validate['txtUlica']['options']['regexp'] : "" ) . "'"
    . ", '{$greske['txtUlica']}', "
    . "'" . ( isset($def['txtUlica']) ? $def['txtUlica'] : "" ) . "'"
    . ")"; ?>"
```

Ugly as sin but it should work.

You should end up with the JavaScript function call looking something like:

```
proveriPolje(this, 'DATA FROM PHP VAR', 'DATA FROM PHP VAR', 'DATA FROM PHP VAR')
```

Comment: Updated - I'd lost track of the brackets ... I've also added ' marks around the first parameter

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your php tags around the variables. php can not know what this javascript function should do.

```
onblur="proveriPolje(this, {<?= $validate['txtUlica']['options']['regexp'] ?>}, '{<?= $greske['txtUlica'] ?>}', '{<?= $def['txtUlica'] ?>}')"; ?>"
```

Comment: problem is proveriPolje() is javascript function this whole code is in javascript, in your way function is in php

Comment: No it is not, The `<?=` and `?>` make sure that only the variables are seen as php code. The function shouldn't be between php tags otherwise the function is seen as php code.

Answer (score 0):

eval()? Or simple echo?
Since you dont print it this is just a string
Btw is this a file, processed by php or a single html? I know its a dumb question but I have just saw a qiestion where the code was ran from html and that was the origin of the problem.

Comment: `<?= ?>` echoes the variable between the tags. :)

Comment: And is this short tag enabled on the server?

Comment: this is set by default on the server for the new PHP version... you don't need to specify this

Comment: Quite strange style... Anyway didnt you missed the concatenation dot? Or this style does not need it?